# Empty properties on a single line

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

With resharper:
It turns

```
 public int Body { get; }
```

Into

```
 public int Body 
 { 
   get; 
 }
```

How can I get it to keep it the way I have above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for. Let me know how it works for you:

1. Go to Resharper -> Options.
2. On Left tree view Expand Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping.
3. On the right view, scroll down to Other Section and ensure the following option is checked.

[image: Auto property on single line]

I'm using R# 2017.2.1.

Hope this helps!